# Gracefully resigning from an unmaintainable project I was hired to work on urgently

Tags: resignation, software-development, software, expectations

I was hired by a big company, but lately I found myself in a delicate situation. Big companies have more formal processes, adopt methodologies, are up to date/speed. I have enough experience that I attracted calls from head hunters. I accepted an offer from an ex-employer, who hired me on the fly, less than an hour after the job interview. I needed more time to think, but they put pressure on me, so I had to accept.

The problem I am having right now is that their software is not maintainable at all. It's a Java project made with COBOL mindset, maybe 20 years ago. They definitely can't retain personnel with such low code quality.

I have already quit a previous job because the project was in crisis and the guy who hired me wanted me to do something for an already lost cause. For the time being, I felt I was very welcomed and they were very attentive to all my logistical needs.

How can I gracefully resign?

Comment: How long ago were you hired exactly?

Comment: One week as a freelancer.

Comment: Oh boy, and how long for is the contract you've signed?

Comment: I can leave at anytime, but I will lose the trust of a recruiter.

Comment: So the contract has no notice periods, no length etc?

Comment: Exactly, it's based on trust.

Comment: What do they want you to do with it? Are they willing to have it migrated to a more maintainable form, or do they only want bugfixes because they're afraid any change will break it? The former could be challenging and fun, the latter could be frustrating.

Comment: I was hired to work on bugfixes. I spent a whole day debugging some function I couldn't grasp any logic.

Comment: "I needed more time to think, but they did put a pressure on me, so I had to accept." That's your mistake.

Comment: What makes you want to quit this job, it sounds like an interesting challenge?

Comment: You have a contract stating exactly how soon and how you should resign.  Follow that to the letter.

Comment: Also, they apparently pay you too little to just take it as a learning experience.

Comment: Could you clarify "Big companies ... are up to date/speed".

Comment: Second @AdamBurke's point. Big companies are not necessarily any more up to date on best practices than small ones are. Sometimes less so because "the old way has always worked well enough." Don't assume that moving will address your concerns; the lesson here is that if you aren't willing to deal with legacy code and legacy environments you need to nail that down during the interview process ... And being inflexible about this will reduce the number of opportunities available to you.

Comment: Also, *everyone* struggled to debug code that isn't already loaded into their minds, which means every new team member, no matter how experienced, struggles until they have worked with the system enough to understand it's structure and assumptions. It sounds like the problem may partly be that you just aren't used to coming into an established nontrivial codebase and are expecting it to be easy when you should be expecting it to be hard but educational. Changing companies may not solve that either.

Comment: @keshlam +1, and OP will no doubt find out the hard way that companies don't want primadonnas who make it clear in the interview that they only want to work on greenfield projects where they can do it the way they want...

Comment: @FioratheFerret, I think you're failing to put it in context. A lot of companies have real crap code that was written as greenfield by inexperienced young developers, who have all since bailed out. The company then wants to hire someone else to work with unfathomable nonsense, either another cheap young developer who is still wanting to learn (either learn alone, or from experts, not to deal single-handedly with someone else's nonsense), or an old hand who knows it's fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @Steve, Yes, there's a lot of poor code out there, and a lot of projects that were good at the time but the industry's moved on. Starting from scratch each time a codebase reaches a certain level of obsoleteness isn't a viable strategy for businesses, and changing jobs each time you're faced with such a codebase isn't a viable strategy for an employee. Handling and improving legacy effectively is a vitally important skill.

Comment: ... and one that will certainly keep you in work

Comment: @FioratheFerret, the OP said he'd worked for his current employer before, and obviously left on good terms. There are a variety of viable strategies for development, but if a company allows all existing developers to depart and the development team becomes completely vacant (and I gather that's what happened prior to the OP), usually they are finished once and for all with that codebase (whether they like it or not).

Answer (score 26):

> The problem I am having right now, is that their software is not maintainable at all.

It is a thing every manager in the software industry hears from so many new hires and contractors that it feels like it should be on some bingo card. And am I yet to run into singular instances where that resulted in that manager going “Oh golly, how did I not think about it before?!” and ordering an instant rewrite.

You took a job to maintain a piece of software, it may not be pretty, and it may not be easy, but that's the job you took. After a week you are looking for a way out, maybe because it's beyond your skill, or you don't want to deal with it. Neither of those options paints you in a great light, especially when it seems to me that they are going above and beyond to accommodate you.

But to answer your question of:

> How can I gracefully resign?

The answer would be: “the sooner the better”. I would skip getting into the whole “this is such a mess I can't/won't even bother to fix it” as you are not stating anything new, or offering a solution ("we need to rewrite is [almost] never a solution, at most a starting point"), so it won't help you. So I would just keep it simple that it's not working out and rip off the bandaid as soon as possible.

But to answer the unasked question:

> What would be the professional thing to do?

The professional thing to do is to continue doing your job for duration of the contract.

If you are worried that you may be unable to maintain the software at a fast enough pace, have a talk about expectations with the manager about what realistically you can deliver daily/weekly etc in terms of improvements. Then if there is some big misalignment, say you can only deliver X, but they expect X*10, that's a solid reason to get out of the whole deal, as no one is going to be happy.

But the reverse is also quite possible, that while you think that you may be expected to deliver X*10, they may be ecstatic with 50% of X, simply due to awareness how hard and annoying it is to maintain the software. You won't know until you have that conversation.

Comment: Typo: ecstatic. Not that I haven't been typo-challenged myself recently, due to typing on a phone...

Comment: This is a very good answer!

Answer (score 6):

This is not a long-term solution for the company.  They have to rebuild their application if their application is unmaintainable; as you said, nobody will want to work there if their code is garbage.

You were hired to fix the problem, and so you should fix the problem.  Tell them: "Your code is unmaintainable and it is impossible to fix it.  We need to rebuild this application in order to get it into a working state, using modern processes and technology, and the sooner we get started the better.  It will take X time to make this work, and that is not negotiable; patching this issue is not feasible".

Then, see what they say.  If they say "ok go ahead", then start rebuilding the application as best as you can.  If they say "no, we can't afford that cost", then simply resign.  It doesn't matter if you resign "gracefully" or not; you told them what needs to be done, and they refused to do it, so end of story.

Comment: I was told in the interview the code was made with old frameworks. I was not told it looks like infinite newspaper.

Comment: If you didn't ask for more details on what that meant, and what they wanted done with it, that's on you.

Comment: @oldavenger No company is going to tell you their codebase is shit.  Both because no company honestly believes their codebase is shit (otherwise they'd do something about it) and because any applicant who hears their prospective company's codebase is shit is going to run away as fast as they can, as you are now realizing.  The solution, therefore, is to make the codebase not shit in the best way you can, and that starts with getting buy-in from management.

Comment: “We need to rebuild this” — Yes, but that doesn't necessarily mean a throw-it-away-and-rewrite-it-from-scratch rebuild. In my experience, evolution is often better than revolution: have a rough idea of how you want it to work, and then work towards that step by step. Much less risk — especially if you have automated tests to show that nothing was broken (or if you haven't, then now would be a good time to write some!). And you can do it alongside business-as-usual work: whenever you work on part of the system, improve it. (Always a good principle, I find.)

Comment: "Nobody will want to work there if their code is garbage". Yes they will if they pay enough.

Comment: @gidds, the process of rewriting is usually to rebuild the knowledge of the *developer* (after an exodus, or 100% turnover). They often won't be able to evolve the existing code, because the new developer won't understand it. Even with automated tests, if someone doesn't readily understand how their recent change is triggering the failure, they may simply alter the code until it fits into a gap in the test coverage. Or, if the change they make is expected to require a change to tests, then they will alter the tests but not know what the new test should look like.

Answer (score 4):

As @TymoteuszPaul says, every manager has heard this one before.

In my view, it is a common refrain because too many companies who are in the market to hire, have low-grade software and/or a workforce who have turned over more than 100% since the beginning (and that turnover is why they are once again hiring).

If you have enough age and experience to give you some clout with the company that have hired you, and if you see no way forward, then I would suggest calling a meeting and explaining your findings, that you don't believe you're going to be able to work with this code base.

Avoid the hackneyed keyword "unmaintainable" and other generalities about the style of the code, and just stick to the fact that having had a chance to review the code base (if you think a week is a reasonable chance), you're just not seeing something you can work with or get to grips with.

If there is no documentation of a genuinely good standard (bearing in mind this is often poor and perfunctory, where it even exists), nor any other member of staff who understands the code deeply, is a good communicator, and to whom you can refer, then you can add that there is a total absence of normal resource required to get to grips with a complicated codebase.

If you're not bound by a notice period, you have only been there a week (per your comments) and you were offered the job on the spot after the interview, then it sounds like both sides could write it off as "easy come easy go" (unless somehow there was a long prelude where they were waiting for you to start).

I would try first to gain their consent to your departure though, rather than just throwing down the towel.

Answer (score 3):

First you decide whether the job pays you what you are worth. Then since you apparently don’t like the job, you decide whether the money compensated you for the displeasure. And usually jobs come with an official probation period, so for a contracting job an unofficial two week probation period is fine.

If you decide to do the job: Don’t care that their code is rubbish. Find how it can be improved bit by bit, then create a list of what needs improving first, and improve things but by bit. Unit tests are your friend. Source code control and code reviews are. If there is bureaucracy in your way, don’t do it. Otherwise take your money and do the job but by bit.

I had a job - not quite as bad - moving a very large project from MacOS 9 to macOS X. Switched the project to MacOS X, pressed “build” and got 4,000 errors. Only 4,000 because the compiler stopped after 99 errors in one source file. Started with the first source file, fixed all the errors, down from 4,000 to 3,950 errors. After six months, the project built - and crashed within 1ms after launching. You’ll probably take longer.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I gracefully resign?

Dear Manager,

I am writing to inform you that I am resigning from my position as Urgent Cobolic Java Maintainer. As a professional courtesy, I am offering to remain until May 11th to hand off my work. Please get in touch with me to let me know which final date you would prefer me to have.

Working at Acme has been a wonderful journey and I am grateful to you for your support and guidance.

Respectfully,